# Sources for the world being round in the Gemara

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, geography, creation

Can anyone bring me proofs from the Gemara that proves the world was round-and that this was known 2000+ years ago?

I have looked around and I can't seem to find any sources which prove this.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36845/zohars-knowledge-about-earths-shape/36847#36847

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22852

Comment: Do you mean circular or spherical?

Comment: @mevaqesh well thank g -d chazal did as per my answer below :)

Comment: Wasn't this more or less _generally_ known at the time of the gemara?

Comment: Note: they're is almost no material in the Talmud that proves anything about 2000 plus years ago.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Gemara in Avoda Zarah (41a) says:

> כדור שתופש את עצמו תחת כל העולם כולו ככדור
>
> ---
>
> It [The Idol] holds a ball as if to say it rules over the entire
>   world like a ball

Tosfos explains why a ball is used as the imagery of ruling over the world (S.V K'kadur) says:

> ככדור. שהעולם עגול כדאיתא בירושלמי שאלכסנדרוס מוקדון עלה למעלה עד
>   שראה כל העולם ככדור ואת הים כקערה פי' ים אוקינוס שמקיף את כל העולם:
>
> ---
>
> "Because the World is round"

Tosfos references a [Yerushalmi](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Avodah_Zarah.18b.1?with=all&lang=bi) which echoes this point:

> "Alexander the Macedonian ascended on high until he saw the earth like
>   a ball and the sea like a platter. The 'sea' refers to the ocean that
>   encompasses the entire earth"

We see here that Chazal (as well as the Romans, as they were discussing Roman idols) had the knowledge that the world was round.

Without getting into claims of the veracity of the Zohar’s claimed authorship. The accepted traditional understanding is that it was authored by Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai, who lived during the Tannaic period. Supposedly the Zohar makes the statement that the world is round (Though i have attempted to look for this source and have not been successful in locating it)

Comment: This is a good answer (and +1), but it would be greatly improved if it featured a translation into English. Especially of the passage in the Yerushalmi, since that's the part that best answers the question that was asked.

Comment: I haven't looked it up, but just from what you copied here of the tosafos I don't see it as difficult? "The world is spherical, as it says in the Yerushalmi: Alexander the Macedonian ascended on high until he saw the earth like a ball and the sea like a platter. The 'sea' refers to the ocean that encompasses the entire earth".

Comment: @Nafkamina Looks like an accurate translation to me.

Comment: Could someone translate this for me please?

Comment: See also my discussion of this Yerushalmi, about a ball on a plate. http://parsha.blogspot.com/2010/11/alexander-great-ball-on-plate-and-snake.html

Comment: Note that the one bringing this information is Alexander (So it might be more accurate to say the Romans as well as Chazal).
I don't have it near me at the moment, but someone was nice enough to write a comprehensive work regarding science and Torah. He shows quite a few mistaken proofs and knowledge we related to Chazal that the ancient world also knew about. For example - Molad, cites which do not match the entire topic (between them the above mentioned Zohar) and more. If I see it again I'll try to put sources.

Comment: @zeev the question asks about chazal

Comment: The source in the Zohar seems to be [here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%92_%D7%99_%D7%90) (דהא כל ישובא מתגלגלא בעיגולא ככדור, found from [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22852/1569))

Comment: You confuse round and spherical. There's nothing new in seeing the flat earth round (כ-דור)  The 3D interpretation by Tosfos as "playing ball" came much much later.

Comment: Also the ocean that surrounds the world is what is beneath it, the continent is like a disk that rests on that waters. The famous argument with Greeks was about and the Sages agreed that the sun warms the ocean from beneath at night. You good answer shows how biased we are to skew the texts into our current worldview.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the earth was a sphere was well known to the Greeks (~2200 years ago), and therefore it would not be surprising that the authors of the Talmud (~1500 years ago) knew about this as well.

However, it seems that the rabbis in the Talmud did not ascribe to this view. They claimed that the earth is flat, covered by a dome, and that the sun went above the dome at night as mentioned some times in the Talmud, in Baba Batra 25b for instance:

> רבי יהושע אומר עולם לקובה הוא דומה ורוח צפונית מסובבת וכיון שחמה מגעת לקרן מערבית צפונית מקפת וחוזרת אחורי כיפה

This dome was perceived as having a window in which the sun goes through at dusk / dawn, as the targum on Kohelet states:

> אזיל כל סטר דרומא ביממא ומחזר לסטר ציפונא בליליא אורח תהומא מחזר מחזר ואזיל לרוח עיבר דרומא בתקופת ניסן ותמוז ועל סחרנוהי תיב לרוח עיבר ציפונא בתקופת תשרי וטבת נפיק מחרכי מדינחא בצפרא ואעיל לחרכי מערבא בשמשא

This idea even made it's way into the modern day prayer book:

> הפותח בכל יום דלתות שערי מזרח ובוקע חלוני רקיע מוציא חמה ממקומה ולבנה ממכון שבתה

So, the proof you are looking for does not really exist, since the rabbis of the talmud explicitly dismissed the Greek model. The fact that subsequent generations of rabbis interpreted the Talmud to refer to a spherical earth as in the answer above, does not actually say anything about the view of the rabbis themselves, which as shown, did not support a spherical earth.

**Addendum:** Just found that Natan Slifkin has written quite a long piece on the subject, bringing many additional sources to support the claim made in this answer: [The Sun's Path At Night](http://www.zootorah.com/RationalistJudaism/TheSunsPathAtNight.pdf).

Comment: So how do you explain the Talmud passages brought by the other answer?

Comment: @Ploni - there is only one passage which is rather ambiguous. The fact that commentators living a thousand years later interpreted that single passage to mean the earth was round should not be taken as evidence, especially given the explicit multiple quotes showing the contrary.

Comment: @Ploni - in addition, the Yerushalmi quote is misunderstood - it refers to the earth looking like a circle surrounded by an ocean, not a sphere.

Comment: How is it ambiguous? It says clearly כדור which means a ball!

Comment: And the Yerushalmi also says כדור. So you're telling me that כדור is a circle, not a ball?

Comment: @ploni - ככדור. Like a sphere, looked at from above. In other words, a circle. Check out the blog post in the comments of the previous answer.